# Prevent uninstalling android app with password like Applock does?

Tags: android

I am developing an parent control security application in android and i want to restrict(asking to enter password) child uninstalling an app?

I tried to implement this with Device Administrator but it has only disable option but i want to ask password from user and it provided password is right then will allow them to uninstall.

If you look at [Applock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock&hl=en) it has similor functionality.

Could anyone give me some directions and code sample how to achive this..?